# What is causing these artifacts in RegionPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, regions

I have a simple program like this:

```
length = 10;
o = {0, 0, 0};
dp = 0.25 (*m*);
rho = 2345 (*kg/m^3*);
rho = dp^3*rho;
region = Cuboid[o, o + length];
cavity = Table[Ball[RandomPoint[region], RandomReal[{0.6 dp, 1.5 dp}]], 4];
region = Fold[RegionDifference, region, cavity];
RegionPlot3D[region, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

What is causing the artifacts that are marked with red arrows? I think the problem is derived from `PlotPoints`, but how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `RegionPlot3D`. The mesh is obviously incorrect and some faces are turned inside out

```
region = RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[{.5, .5, .5}, .2]];
RegionPlot3D[region, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], FaceForm[Red, Blue]], 
 Mesh -> All, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotPoints -> 13, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image]

You can use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` instead

```
dr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[region];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Opacity[0.1]], Opacity[0.5, Orange], 
  GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[dr], MeshCells[dr, 2]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does a good job when the size of the cavity is of larger, but [when the cavity spheres are smaller](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Kx50sjz1), the cavity can sometimes not show up - or if it does it doesn't really look spherical.  Is this a problem with the discretization process or with `RegionDifference`?

Comment: @JasonB You can specify small `MaxCellMeasure` for `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`. Unfortunately `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`do not work here.

Comment: Oh~How nice job!Thanks very much.If you can extinguish the mesh of cell,I will appreciate you and accept it.

Comment: @yode - to get rid of the mesh, inside the `Graphics3D`, change it to say `EdgeForm[Opacity[0.0]]`

Comment: Not sure why, when I change the `EdgeForm[Opacity[...]]` from 0.1 to 0.0, the mesh goes away.  See the edits to my answer

Comment: @yode You can disable the mesh with `EdgeForm[]`.

Comment: @ybeltukov Oh~I have done it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Are you creating a region to do other calculations in, or are you just trying to plot a cube with several spherical cavities in it?  If you are just trying to make the plot, I suggest not using `RegionDifference`.  As I show below the plots, it is only an approximate function, and it fails a bit when the cavities are much smaller than the cube.

Here is the best plot I can make:

```
(* Define the cube, the cavities, and the difference region *)
length = 10;
o = {0, 0, 0};
dp = 0.25 (*m*);
rho = 2345 (*kg/m^3*);
rho = dp^3*rho;
cube = Cuboid[o, o + length];
cavity = Table[
   Ball[RandomPoint[cube], RandomReal[{0.6 dp, 1.5 dp}]], 4];
region = Fold[RegionDifference, cube, cavity];

(* Then observe the difference between the plot with and without RegionDifference *)

Show[RegionPlot3D[#, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 20] & /@
   Join[{cube}, cavity]]
```

[image]

versus

```
RegionPlot3D[region, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

For comparison, let's look at the method given by @ybeltukov, with the mesh taken out as you requested,

```
dr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[region];
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Opacity[0.0]], Opacity[0.5, Orange], 
  GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[dr], MeshCells[dr, 2]]}]
```

[image]

This is indeed better than just doing a `RegionPlot3D` on `region`, but it fails to make the cavities look spherical and it doesn't show all of the cavities.  So in my opinion, the only way to make this plot well is to skip `RegionDifference` and just plot the cube and the spheres together.

But perhaps you are creating the `RegionDifference` in order to use it in calculations.  One way to do this, is to do a three dimensional integral of some function over the region.  Below, I run a test by integrating a simple function over the region defined by `RegionDifference`, and comparing this to the result you get by simply taking the difference of the integrals (integrate over the cube, then subtract the integrals over the cavities).  The results should be identical:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[y + z - x], {x, y, z} ∈ region]
NIntegrate[Sin[y + z - x], {x, y, z} ∈ cube] - 
 Total@(NIntegrate[Sin[y + z - x], {x, y, z} ∈ #] & /@ cavity)
(* 6.57153 - 1.70511*10^-21 I *)
(* 6.5671 *)
```

They agree remarkably well, but not exactly.  The integral over the `RegionDifference` took over ten times as long, and also returned convergence errors.

Comment: Thanks for your pay attention to this problem.But as your see,the `RegionPlot[Disk[]]` should not give a right plot.BTW.what's meaning of your `x^2 + Sqrt[y + z]`?

Comment: @yode, I'm not sure what you mean by "should not give a right plot".  Check the post, I updated it.  I think the only way to get the plot you want is to not use `RegionDifference`

Comment: I think your answer is nice,too.I'm feel so sorry.Thanks all the same.

Comment: @yode - nothing to be sorry about, whatever works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
length = 10;
o = {0, 0, 0};
dp = 0.25 ;

region = Cuboid[o, o + length];
cavity = Table[Ball[{1, 1, 1}, RandomReal[{0.6 dp, 1.5 dp}]], {k, 4}];

Show[RegionPlot3D[region, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 10],
RegionPlot3D[cavity, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]]
] // Timing
```

You can change `{1, 1, 1}` with your definition of `RandomPoint[].`

Comment: Thanks a lot,but the last region is expected,then I wanna visualize it.You just do the latter.